# How to transform a knowledge base (CNF) from propositional logic in a set?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I have a proposition logic knowledge base which contains my neg query in CNF:
$$\begin{split}1.~& \neg P \lor Q\\
3.~& P \\
4.~& R \lor S\\
5.~& \neg R\end{split}$$

Is it possible to transfer them into set theory? Are all these syntacitally and semantically correct?

$$ K =\{(\neg P \lor Q), (P), (R \lor S), (\neg R) \}$$
$$ K =\{\{\neg P \lor Q\}, \{P\}, \{R \lor S\}, \{\neg R\} \}$$
$$ K =\{\{\neg P , Q\}, \{P\}, \{R , S\}, \{\neg R\} \}$$

Answer (score 1):

All are valid representations of a CNF, depending on the task.

The first is a set of predicates, which so happen to all be disjunctions or literals.   When the set is read conjunctively, this is a CNF.

The second is a set of clauses, several of which have terms which are disunctions rather than literals or negated literals.   This is ... not wrong, but rarely used as is.

The third is a set of clauses, each of which are sets of literals or negations of literals.   This is the *preferred* representation when the task is resolution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would it be wrong and why not using "," betwen sets of literals in the last one: $ K =\{\{\neg P , Q\} \{P\} \{R , S\} \{\neg R\} \}$?